# How to authenticate using cross domain query

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to integrate my application with other web site .in this my web site will send post request to some other web site on behalf of the user so this will set cookies in user browser than it will redirect user to that site so user does  not need to provide authentication detail.

How can i implement this since ajax does not make call to cross domain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how you can do cross domain calls with AJAX:
http://coding4life.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/making-cross-domain-calls-in-signalr/
(**Disclaimer:** It's my personal blog)

It uses SignalR, but internally this is using jQuery. To active cross domain calls in jQuery you have to use:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use ajax call but parse it through a proxy! Check this link for more details.

http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/docs/files/ba-simple-proxy-php.html

With some tweaks into php files that are remote you can make it work without proxy but not on Internet Explorer.

I use that proxy on my cross domain calls within an application and works very well.

**Careful** If you want to pass parameters in links you will have to encode to HTML the characters like this:

```
/ = %2F
: = %3A
& = %26
 (space) = %2520
```

otherwise the proxy php file will throw you an error.

On that site there is an working example and you can test the output.

Hope this helps you in the cross domain problem. For me it worked.

Comment: but sir in case of proxy how it will work since cookies is need to be set in client browser

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mention you could use a proxy or cors. But be aware that cors is not compatible with some older browsers.

The other option is to use jsonp to make the cross domain call.

Comment: sir can i use the same foe sending post request .if yes then can you please paste code snippet of the same

Comment: No you can't make a post request using jsonp, it's Get only. But you can append querystring parameters to the request url, so you can send small ammounts of data like this (which is what jQuery does for sending data in Get ajax requests).