# How to retrieve specific data from json,the json values comes from a url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have tried other questions on the same issue to retrieve data from JSON. But none of them worked for me as my JSON data is different from others.

Maybe my question sounds same as others questions, but I have tried everything.

```
[  
   {  
      "bHeader":{  
         "ei":"NSE",
         "seg":"I"
      },
      "cNetChangeIndicator":"\u0000",
      "fClosingIndex":10558.5,
      "fHighIndexValue":10532.0,
      "fIndexValue":10469.0,
      "fLowIndexValue":10438.5,
      "fOpeningIndex":10499.5,
      "fPercentChange":-0.85,
      "sIndexName":"962450",
      "fChange":-89.5,
      "iIdxId":311
   }
]
```

Please help me out in finding the values

```
fIndexValue
fChange
fPercentChange.
```

Comment: what is the expected output and what issue are you facing with your attempt?

Comment: the issue is that I am not getting the values  fIndexValue,fChange,fPercentChange.I have tried this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443466/pull-data-from-json-format-using-jquery".But my json is in different format

Comment: Can you share your attempt as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var data = [{"bHeader":{"ei":"NSE","seg":"I"},"cNetChangeIndicator":"\u0000","fClosingIndex":10558.5,"fHighIndexValue":10532.0,"fIndexValue":10469.0,"fLowIndexValue":10438.5,"fOpeningIndex":10499.5,"fPercentChange":-0.85,"sIndexName":"962450","fChange":-89.5,"iIdxId":311}];

data.forEach(function(item){
  console.log('fIndexValue:'+ item.fIndexValue);
  console.log('fChange:'+ item.fChange);
  console.log('fPercentChange:'+ item.fPercentChange);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You can use `json_decode(json_string, true)` php function like below

```
$str = '[{"bHeader":{"ei":"NSE","seg":"I"},"cNetChangeIndicator":"\u0000","fClosingIndex":10558.5,"fHighIndexValue":10532.0,"fIndexValue":10469.0,"fLowIndexValue":10438.5,"fOpeningIndex":10499.5,"fPercentChange":-0.85,"sIndexName":"962450","fChange":-89.5,"iIdxId":311}]';

$arr = json_decode($str, true);

print_r($arr);

echo $arr[0]['fIndexValue'];
echo $arr[0]['fChange'];
echo $arr[0]['fPercentChange'];
```

For refresh page every 30s. write code below.

```
// write the function
function refresh($time)
{
    $current_url = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
    return header( "Refresh: " . $time . "; URL=$current_url" );
}

// call the function in the appropriate place
refresh(30);
// this refreshes page after 4 seconds
```

Comment: This doesn't print anything                                                                        echo $arr[0]['fIndexValue'];
echo $arr[0]['fChange'];
echo $arr[0]['fPercentChange'];Also the $str values are dynamic which comes from url,so I need to refresh that url say after 30 secs.I have used Curl but it's not doing the task.My email id is- anindya12.it@gmail.com

Comment: I'm getting the total array not these values separately                                                                         echo $arr[0]['fIndexValue'];
echo $arr[0]['fChange'];
echo $arr[0]['fPercentChange'];

Comment: in this print_r($arr); array you can see whole values in array you have passed in json. you can get value using this array

Answer (score 0):

have you try with JSON.parse(request)? you will be able to acces as an object

Comment: Hi Pablo Fuentes,could you throw some light on that as I don't know Json that well

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$data = '[  
   {  
      "bHeader":{  
         "ei":"NSE",
         "seg":"I"
      },
      "cNetChangeIndicator":"\u0000",
      "fClosingIndex":10558.5,
      "fHighIndexValue":10532.0,
      "fIndexValue":10469.0,
      "fLowIndexValue":10438.5,
      "fOpeningIndex":10499.5,
      "fPercentChange":-0.85,
      "sIndexName":"962450",
      "fChange":-89.5,
      "iIdxId":311
   }
]';

$data = json_decode($data);
foreach ($data as $d){
   echo  $d->fIndexValue;
   echo  $d->fChange;
   echo  $d->fPercentChange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your json is 2 dimension so you should try something like

`data[0]['fHighIndexValue']`

looking in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/scnx3vh4/